# Invisible Layout not visible when make it visible in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I am trying to implement something like viewing a list of items in RecyclerView (id=schedule_recycler_view) which parent layout is a CardView (id = info_card_view). The Item is fetched by API call. If no item found, or connectivity issue, I want to view another layout (id = no_list_layout) which is Visibility-Gone at the first time.

But The problem I face, although I make the visibility of that layout (id = no_list_layout) visible programmatically, it did not visible.

Can anyone help?

Here the code what I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView/>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView/>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/_90sdp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_schedule_image_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white_with_blue_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline" />


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/info_card_view"
        style="@style/CardViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_200sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_bar_layout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/schedule_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/no_list_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/not_found_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_schedule"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/not_found_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="No Invoice"
                 />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in kotlin file

```
    class TutorScheduleFragment : BaseFragment() {



    private val tuitionScheduleAdapter by lazy {
        TutorScheduleAdapter {
            context?.showToast(it.day)
        }
    }

    private val viewModel: TutorScheduleViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            TutorScheduleViewModel(
                PreferenceService(context?.getSharedPreference()!!)
            )
        }
    }

    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_tutor_schedule

    override fun onResume() {
        viewModel.getSchedule(jobTutorId!!)
    }

    override fun observeLiveData() {
        viewModel.tuitionScheduleUiState.observe(this@TutorScheduleFragment, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { state ->
                when (state) {

                    is Progress -> {
                        if (state.isLoading) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    is Success -> {
                        val schedules = state.successInfo.data


                        if (scheduleData.schedules.size == 0) {
                            no_list_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        } else {                                 

              tuitionScheduleAdapter.notifyChanged(scheduleData.schedules)
                        }

                    }

                    is Alert -> context?.showToast(state.alert)

                    is Failure -> {
                        if (state.throwable is IOException) {
                            context?.showToast("Internet Connection Failed")
                        } else {
                            context?.showToast("Json Parsing Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })


    }

}
```

Comment: IF my answer did not solve your issue please post more information about your code

Comment: @Alan thanks, bro for your answer. but I already did that. in fact, visible() is an extension function I already write for all views.
fun View.visible() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

Comment: @AlanDeep bro, what information do you want. Please let me know

Comment: @Omi Solved this yet?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes brother. I solved that after redesigning the layout. Thanks a lot brother for your great effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the actual culprit. It was in the layout file. I recreate the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/info_card_view"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_light_blue_top_info_holder"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/upcoming_action_text_view"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle.Bold"
            android:text="Upcoming Test"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle.Bold"
            android:text="16 Aug, Wednesday"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upcoming_action_text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_action_image_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/upcoming_action_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_text_view" />

        <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.WormDotsIndicator
            android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:dotsColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:dotsSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:dotsSpacing="@dimen/_2sdp"
            app:dotsStrokeColor="@color/light_blue"
            app:dotsStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upcoming_action_view_pager" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/previous_action_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_bar_layout"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_previous_action_of_confirm_job" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_bar_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/not_found_image_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_schedule" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/not_found_text_view"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle.Center.Bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
            android:text="No Invoice" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `no_list_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

Answer (score 1):

Change your view visibility code

try this :

**Kotlin:**

```
if (list.size == 0) {
    no_list_layout.visibility= View.VISIBLE
} else {
    adapter.notifyChanged(list)
}
```

**In Java**

```
if (list.size == 0) {
        no_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    } else {
        adapter.notifyChanged(list)
    }
```

Comment: thanks, bro for your answer. but I already did that. in fact, visible() is an extension function I already write it for all views. fun View.visible() { visibility = View.VISIBLE }

Comment: I posted my Fragment class. Please have a look

Comment: print scheduleData.schedules.size and state in logcat and check conditions are working or not.

Comment: it's working bro. when size > 0, list is shown. but when list == 0 nothing happen. I think the problem is in the layout

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **`runOnUiThread`**.

> [**`runOnUiThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the
>   current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed
>   immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is
>   posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

```
context?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
    // Your Logic
  if (list.size==0) {
       no_list_layout.visibility= View.VISIBLE
  } else {
       // Your work
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide your recyclerview also and make it visible in the other case like this:

```
if (scheduleData.schedules.size == 0) {
    schedule_recycler_view.visibility = View.GONE
    no_list_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
} else {   
    schedule_recycler_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    no_list_layout.visibility = View.GONE                              
    tuitionScheduleAdapter.notifyChanged(scheduleData.schedules)
}
```